# Is there a simple way to find the inverse of matrices in $\text{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Tags: matrices, binary, python

I am using Python and I noticed that there seems no implementation that enables one to invert a binary matrix. Aka, I want to find $A^{-1}$ for any invertible $A \in \text{SL}{(n,\mathbb{Z}_2)}$.

Can anyone tell me if I can do so in any way in Python? Thanks!

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Important_consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Important_consequence)

Comment: Emmm... could you please give more hints? I think to get the adjugate is not easy as well?

Comment: Why not getting the usual (real valued) $A^{-1}$ then rounding to the next integer every entry ?

Comment: $A^{|G|-1}$ where $|G|$ is the number of elements of the group

Comment: Is there a specific time complexity you're aiming for? Why do the standard methods not suffice here for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this repository helps: https://github.com/xiangzejun/binary_matrix

This repository used Python to implement a module that enables one to do things like checking invertibility, finding the inverse, calculate rank, etc. The only problem is that the repository was written in Python 2. I manually converted it to Python 3.

Comment: perhaps include a summary so that others don't have to click on the link.